# Large data downloads from a Web app to Android client getting Out of memory error

Tags: android, bufferedreader, out-of-memory

I'm sending the following request to a Web app running on Tomcat:

```
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("email_addr=" + URLEncoder.encode(email_addr, "UTF-8") + "&" + "passwd=" + 
    URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&" +
    "cmd=" + tmp + "&" + "parms=" + URLEncoder.encode(parms, "UTF-8"));
writer.close();
```

and the read the response as follows:

```
rdr  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
tmp = rdr.readLine();
```

Everything works fine as long as the data coming back is less than around 5 MB. Then I get an error on readLine():

> 04-02 16:51:34.232: E/dalvikvm-heap(3907): Out of memory on a 10309582-byte allocation

With 512 MB of RAM, I don't see why it's running out of space. Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That 512MB is not all for you. Depending on the device, you application will get 16MB, 24MB, 32MB. If the device has 512MB of memory, it will be 24MB for your application.